# How i can create sliding button like Uber android app

Tags: android

Hi Any One guide me how to create the Uber bottom buttons in Android.
Any sample code or code suggestion.

Uber Bottom buttons for choose car type button

[image: Uber Bottom buttons for choose car type button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the android ui widget `seekbar`. And customize your style.

Comment: Try the following lib:https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar  https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

Comment: @Gjson how to align the images to completely left, center and right. I am not able to remove the padding/ margin left or right of the square and cancel image. I hope you understood my question.